# Inductor core loss for H-bridge type inverter

Tags: inductor, inverter, core

This is not a question about a specific circuit, rather this is a question about a concept.

In a typical switching H-bridge type inverter, which currents contribute to the core loss of the output filter inductors L1, L2?  For the sake of this question it doesn't matter if it is a bipolar or unipolar inverter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO9mb1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A) 60Hz load current

B) Switching ripple current

C) Both 60Hz load and switching ripple current

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think it should be both the 60Hz and high frequency component that contributes to core loss.  The core loss equation is something like k x F^n x B^m.  So even though the B at 60Hz might be pretty big, the F is much smaller than the switching frequency.

Comment: There is more core loss in Polar example due to narrower async pulses yet less conduction loss in windings being switched at 1/2 the voltage. So it depends on differences power spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

### Inverter Topology vs inductor Core loss.

**Assume H-bridge topology.**

**Edit:  Change assumption from Polar referring to DC voltages not Drivers.**

According to recent papers e.g. A Namboodiri

- Bi Polar DC Voltage with PWM H-Bridge switches all 4 devices in sync to reverse DC voltage to get a differential bipolar output
- Polar DC Voltage with PWM H-Bridge switches only 2 devices asynchronously in 1 polarity and other 2 devices for opposite polarity so only one sine polarity is modulated at a time.

> I leave it to you to analyse each component of core loss and focus on the current spectrum for EC core losses and conductive heat effects on mu.

```
- This Polar config. is what I referred to earlier as 3 level Sine simulation (with PWM)
```

POLAR EXAMPLE 
   - in theory , more efficient drivers, but what is  pulse current , impedance and spectrum for same power out?

[image]

BIPOLAR EXAMPLE

[image]

[image]

### Core Losses

- Hysteresis Core Losses increase with area of the loop from work to reverse flux
- Saturation Core losses increase with loss of margin near saturation
- Eddy current losses resist the velocity of flux reversals and thus are proportional to square of frequency and duration

Eddy current losses Pec are proportional to SQUARE of the frequency spectrum of the current \$f_{-3dB}=0.35/t_R\$ (10~90%) and the square of the current and resulting flux in the core.

[image]

- where:

Ke – co-efficient of eddy current, depends on material
Bm – maximum value of flux density [wb/m2]
T – thickness of lamination [meters]
F – frequency of reversal of magnetic field [Hz]
V – volume of magnetic material [m³]

\$P_EC=k^2fI^2\$ reduced by the time interval 
[image]   [Ref](https://www.solarpowerworldonline.com/2015/02/new-age-solar-inverter-conversion-efficiency-99/)

Comment: You seem to be answering something completely different, and your grammar is a mess.

Comment: Feel free to suggest grammar improvements. I'll update the EC issues. Sometimes a better answer implies a better question not asked. such as the driving voltage that reduces eddy currents.

Comment: Also to compress a book into 1 page takes Brevity. So be sure your comments @WHL are accurate and make suggestions more than armchair criticism.

Comment: I think OP is asking about a hypothetical sine wave inverter, where the transformer is driven with a relatively high frequency square wave (hence question about core losses caused by "switching" ripple current) whose duty cycle is modulated by a 50 or 60 Hz sine wave. I can only guess as OP didn't bother to write a comprehensive question.

Comment: I was assuming the same.   so the PWM modulated 3 level sine wave is found in better inverters and more levels in higher power inverters where losses are significant.  The PWM allows the output voltage to be regulated since the Zo is quite high and load regulation errors can be reduced with secondary feedback using PWM. Zo is a function of {RdsOn+ DCR}*n²

Comment: It seems I assumed wrong about unipolar referrig to drivers rather than DC voltage. So I will edit my response.

Comment: Thanks for modifying your response.  This is not a question about bipolar or unipolar inverters, the hypothetical inverter could be either one.  I know about the core loss equation.  I've reworded the question so that the answer should be A, B, or C.  If there is any confusion as to what I am asking now, let me know.